# Creating unique_ptr of non plain data in C++

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

The ptr constructors works with plain data but fails with objects:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct MyClass{};

int main() {

    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int(5));
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> ptr1(new std::string("string")); //function 'ptr1' could not be resolved.
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr2(new MyClass); //unction 'ptr2' could not be resolved.
    return 0;
}
```

why?

My g++ version is (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.7.3

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Fails... at *run-time*? at *compile-time* ?

Comment: Could you provide minimal failing example, like the one in Mr.C64's answer?

Comment: This can't be right. What's the command line to compile it?

Comment: Eclipse. Ill try in command line.

Comment: Works fine with :g++ -std=c++0x CppTest.cpp   But fails in Eclipse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eclipse+could+not+be+resolved

Comment: This is line to compile in Eclipse: g++ -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"src/CppTest.d" -MT"src/CppTest.d" -o "src/CppTest.o" "../src/CppTest.cpp"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse - Method NewStringUTF() could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899813/eclipse-method-newstringutf-could-not-be-resolved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned it fails in eclipse, so you might try disabling eclipse internal code validation, by:

going to project properties -> C/C++ General  -> Code Analysis -> check `Use project settings` and then in `Syntax and Semantic Errors` uncheck all Error lines.

You might need to delete previous errors from output, by simply selecting them and deleting.

Actually there is one line with pattern 'Function ''{0}'' could not be resolved', normally g++ would not give you such error (I at least never seen such)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, these initializations work just fine - the following code compiles fine e.g. with g++ 4.8.2:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct MyClass { };

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int(5));
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> ptr1(new std::string("string"));
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr2(new MyClass);
}
```