# Best way to send parameter between JNI and C++

Tags: c++, dll, java-native-interface

I had wrote my program using visual studio c++ and now i'm trying to create a dll from that code to use in another java application. For example i have a two function in c++:

```
int  __declspec(dllexport) _stdcall   login(const unsigned char pin[4])
```

and

```
string __declspec(dllexport) _stdcall RNG_Gen (unsigned char* data)
```

Then i followed the instruction of some webpage on how to create a DLL from C++ code for java using JNI, so i include "jni.h" and wrote another function like this to call my function:

for the first function i use :

```
#define JNIEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define JNIIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#define JNICALL __stdcall

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_login
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jbyteArray pin)
 {
    int len = env->GetArrayLength (pin);
        if(len<PIN_SIZE)return -1;
        unsigned char buf[4];// = new unsigned char[len];
    env->GetByteArrayRegion (pin, 0, len, (jbyte *)(buf));
        return login(buf);

 }
```

But what should i do with **`string`** and **`unsigned char*`** in the second function? how should i call that function? how should i send an unsigned char * to that function?  and how can i get the returned string ?

Comment: You don't really give very much information here. Hard to know what your problem is. Although your attempts to return `std::string` are doomed to fail. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hi David, i need to use my c++ code in java so i have to create a dll using JNI. My exact question is how to do this for C++ code **and not C**. because i had used c++ functioalities like `string` and etc

Comment: Please ask a direct and specific question in the question and not in the comments. And no, you won't be able to return `std::string` like that. I know you'd like to do so, but your desire to do so will not make it possible. It will be pure C style POD types across the DLL boundary.

Comment: Please can you ask that in the question rather than comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56532/discussion-between-osyan-and-david-heffernan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already worked out how to use `jbyteArray` for the `unsigned char*` parameter. You do just what you did with the `login` function, calling `GetArrayLength` and `GetByteArrayRegion`. No need for me to repeat that here.

For the string return value you need to use `jstring`, like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_RNG_Gen
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jbyteArray data) 
{
     // do whatever is needed to obtain the result string
     std::string result = ...; 

     // create a new jstring value, and return it
     return env->NewStringUTF(result.c_str());
}
```

Comment: I get **expression must have pointer type** error at `return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, result.c_str());`

Comment: Sorry, mea cupla. I gave you the C syntax rather than C++. See latest version. Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899813/eclipse-method-newstringutf-could-not-be-resolved

Comment: Thanks. Glad to have helped. Especially as I've never written a line of Java or JNI in my life!  ;-)

Comment: :) you have just started 29 minutes ago